# Copying to a new DataFrame but failing on missing column

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing the foll. in pandas:

```
    all_df = pd.DataFrame()
    all_df[self.FAO_code] = per_df[self.FAO_code]
    all_df[self.ISO_code] = per_df[self.ISO_code]
    all_df[self.cft_id] = per_df[self.cft_id]
    all_df[self.cft_type] = per_df[self.cft_type]
```

In some cases, the column self.cft_id is missing in per_df. In such a case, `all_df[self.cft_id] = per_df[self.cft_id]` causes an error. What is the best way to deal with this i.e handle cases where column is missing or not?

1. Wrap in try except. In the except clause, just `pass`

Any other way?

**EDIT**

Part of per_df:

```
   ISO  Country_FAO       funct_type    Y1961    Y1962    Y1963    Y1964 
0    4  Albania             C3annual  3058729  3183956  3214308  3233208   
1    4  Albania          C3perennial    99999   100000   100000   105000   
2    4  Albania             C4annual   523500   524500   525500   531500   
3    4  Albania          C4perennial     1800     1800     1800     1800   
4    4  Albania             N-fixing    20500    21000    22500    22500
```

Comment: Could you show part of you dataframe?

Comment: edited as per request by @AntonProtopopov

Comment: so what is self.cft_id in that dataframe?

Comment: self.cft_id is missing, but in some other dataframes it will be present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter` method. It's ignoring non existing column:

```
all_df = per_df.filter([self.FAO_code, self.ISO_code, self.cft_id, self.cft_type])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
for col in [self.FAO_code, ..., self.cft_type]:
    if col in per_df.columns:
        all_df[col] = per_df.loc[:, col]
```

Comment: thanks @Stefan, why are you using `all_df.loc[:, col] = per_df.loc[:, col]` instead of `all_df.[col] = per_df[col]`?

Comment: Just updated. Assuming you are creating new columns. The previous selection was not going to get you the column from per_df, rather a row index.